# Only 1 out of 2 fields should be filled - Validation Rule on Salesforce

Tags: validation, currency

I have 2 fields and the data type is "currency" for both.
I want to make a validation rule thats says that only one field should be filled in.
If both of them are filled then it should throw an error.

I thought it would be something like this :

```
AND(!ISBLANK( Amount1__c ), !ISBLANK(Amount2__c))
```

Comment: Yep, that validation rule that you have ought to work. Is it not working for you? Is your validation formula set to treat blanks as zeroes instead of as blanks?

Comment: Hello Derek, it is not working.

I also replaced ISBLANK by ISNULL. But when I read the documentation, I see that ISBLANK should be better for my case ? Since it's a currency type.


I also tried this : 
( IF(ISBLANK(Amount1__c),0,1) + 
  IF(ISBLANK(Amount2__c),0,1)
) > 1

Comment: Again, check the blank handling setting for your validation rule. If you're treating blanks as zeroes, then `ISBLANK()` (and `ISNULL()`, but using `ISBLANK()` is generally preferred) will return false (because `0` is not blank, it's 0).

Comment: I am not sure to understand. So what I do for testing is filling both fields with different amounts and not zeros. 

Ex : Amount1 is 34 and Amount2 is 12

And if I do Amount1 is 34 and Amount2 left blank, I am still getting an error.

Comment: You want to "treat blank fields as blanks" https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000233669&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1

Comment: Thank you Derek ! I didn'nt konw about this option and cases. I am a newbie. But when i write my validation rule, i don't have this option. And If I try to edit the field, I don't see it.

Comment: Strongly recommend using `NOT(condition)` rather than `!condition`, as the former is more consistent syntax with other formula functions.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I also tried this way but not working AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Amount1__c)), NOT(ISBLANK(Amount2__c)))

Answer (score 1):

It was not a formula issue, I was recommended to generate a debug log under my name to see the value of those fields when the validation rule triggers:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000366726&language=en_US&mode=1

I checked in the logs and apparently, it already calculates the +20% taxes (for the selected case during my tests) ! If amount1 is filled, amount2 will be calculated according to a specific formula put in the flow.

So there is a conflict !
Thanks for you help !